# How to find the mapping after permutation of a 2-d matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation, repeat

I have two 2-dimensional matrices A,B, where B is produced by a (row-wise) permutation of A. There are a few repetitive records in A (and so in B). I want to find the mapping that produced B. I am using Matlab. Only one solution is sufficient for me.

**Example:**

```
A = [ 2 3 4; 4 5 6; 2 3 4];
B = [ 4 5 6; 2 3 4; 2 3 4];
```

The mapping would be:

```
p = [3 1 2]   // I want this mapping, however the solution p= [2 1 3] is also correct and acceptable
```

where A = B(p,:) in Matlab.   // EDITED

Regards

Comment: How did you priduce `B`?

Comment: I myself do not produce B, but I know it is produced by permuting records in A.

Comment: do you have access to the way it is permuted?

Comment: No. It is not important for me. I only want the permutation, i.e., p in the example above.

Comment: i was asking because if you have access to the permutation process it might make the solution to this problem a **lot** easier.

Comment: I think your first example p is a typo.  With that p, B != A(p,:).  I like [2 1 3] and [2 3 1]

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake. I edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

low hanging fruits first.
Suppose there are **no duplicate rows**:

```
 % compute the permutation matrix
 P = all( bsxfun( @eq, permute( A, [1 3 2]),permute(B,[3 1 2]) ), 3 );
 [~, p] = max(P, [], 2 ); % gives you what you want
```

If there are duplicates, we need to "break ties" in the rows/columns of `P`:

```
 n = size(A,1);
 bt = abs( bsxfun(@minus, 1:n, (1:n)' ) )/n; %//'
 [~, p] = max( P+bt, [], 2 );
```

Comment: +1: Nice solution. I'd also recommend using a tolerance in case of floating point values.

Comment: @EitanT thank for adding my forgotten `bsxfun` ;-) it's so much FUN!

Comment: Please note that there may much number of records (for example 1000 records in d=13 dimensions). I think the approach is not applicable for large datasets! However, I could not understand your code, completely.

Comment: @RezaMortazavi (1) the code will suffer when `n` grows. I believe it will stil work for `n`=O(1000) though. (2) Have you understand the simple case without duplications?

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your help. I am also seeking a solution based on kd-trees which is implemented in knnsearch, however the repetitive records are again the problem. Do you think I can use it for the case.

Comment: If you are concerned with the complexity of my solution, you mught want to cosider [Peter's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17150103/1714410), it seems to be O(nlogn) instead of O(n^2) for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since we know that A and B always have the same rows, let's look for a transformation that will convert each one to a common identical representation.  How about `sort`?

```
[As, Ai] = sortrows(A);
[Bs, Bi] = sortrows(B);
```

Now `A(Ai,:) == B(Bi,:)`, so all we have to do is find the indices for Bi that match Ai.  Bi is a forward mapping, Ai is a reverse mapping.  So:

```
p = zeros(size(A,1),1);
p(Ai) = Bi;
```

*(Answer edited to match edit of problem statement)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `sort()` to get around the problem of needing to generate all permutations.

The idea is to sort both `A` and `B` which will produce the same sorted matrix. The permutation can now be found  by using the indices `IA` and `IB` that produce the two sorted matrices.

```
A = [ 2 3 4; 4 5 6; 2 3 4];
B = [ 4 5 6; 2 3 4; 2 3 4];

[CA,IA]=sort(A,1)
[CB,IB]=sort(B,1)

idxA = IA(:,1)
idxB = IB(:,1)

[~, idxB_inverse] = sort(idxB)

idxA(idxB_inverse)
```